# Subdivide a model with morph targets, Possible?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to figure out if this is possible. If it was it would lower the file size for detailed models with morph targets.
So far my tests have failed and i can find no examples of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be determined from the `THREE.SubdivisionModifier`'s [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js), it does not support morph targets. So you'd need to patch it to make it work. To lower file size of animated objects, using skeletal animation is an option to consider.